# Check box not toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The toggle check box function is only working once and after the first instance it doesnt work. Any help?

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/66gmK/

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#1',function(){

          $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    var Checked = $(this).attr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', !Checked);
  }); 


    });

});
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox"  id="1" value="0" />
    <label for="1" >Toggle All</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="2" value="0" />
  ahmed</p>
  <p>
    <input name="3" type="checkbox" id="3" value="0" />
    <label for="3">omar</label>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, there's something wrong with your jquery, I've updated your code and see if this is what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/66gmK/5/

Answer (score 4):

Move the `Checked` variable out of the each because the `this` context changes in the each, it refers to the checkbox in the loop, not the toggle checkbox. Remove the `!` not operator when changing the checked property. Also use `prop` instead of `attr` for the checked property.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6qVpL/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click','#1',function(){
        var Checked = $(this).prop('checked');  
        $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each(function(){

            $(this).prop('checked', Checked);
        }); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

your jquery
on each function , you should not change the property of toggle checkbox.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click','#1',function(){ 
              $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").not(this).each(function(){             
                var Checked = $(this).prop('checked');          
                $(this).prop('checked', !Checked);
      });       
        });
    });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/66gmK/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#1').on('click',function(){
             var Checked = $(this).prop('checked');
             $.each($("input[type='checkbox']"), function(i,e){
             $(e).prop('checked', Checked);
             });
     });
});
```